Custom logger that is instantiated with tracker id only once
test-executor.py
import CustomLogger
from CustomExecutor import iterative_executor

def main():
    logging = CustomLogger.Logger('sample-run', {
        'cnt' : 10
    })
    logging.info("Starting run")
    iterative_executor(1)
    logging.info("Done with execution")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

CustomExecutor.py
import CustomLogger

# from CustomLogger import Logger as logging
logging = CustomLogger.Logger('sample-run', {
        'cnt' : 10
    })

def iterative_executor(iter_cnt=2):
    for i in range(iter_cnt):
        logging.info(f"Current iteration cnt {i}")

CustomLogger.py
import json
import logging
import os

class StreamLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, k_dict={}, level=logging.DEBUG):
        super().__init__(name, level)

        streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] [%(funcName)s] %(message)s')
        streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.addHandler(streamHandler)

class Logger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, k_dict, level=logging.DEBUG):
        super().__init__(name, level)
        self.k_dict = k_dict
        self.json_logging = False
        if 'TRANSFORM_TO_JSON' in os.environ:
            self.json_logging = True
        self.stream_logger = StreamLogger(name, k_dict)

    def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.json_logging:
            self.stream_logger.info(self._transform_to_json(msg), *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.stream_logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def json_transform(self, msg):
        msg_dict = self.k_dict
        msg_dict['message'] = msg

        return json.dumps(msg_dict)

Code above with CustomLogger to emit a trace id with each and every log message.
It works, if I instantiate the logger as
logging = CustomLogger.Logger('sample-run', {
    'cnt' : 10
})

in every file. I don't want to do that as the tracker / trace id need to be set once as part of instantiating logging via test-executor.py and not in any other code. I want to set the context of track / trace id via test-executor.py and to consume everywhere the custom logger is being used. CustomLogger is more complicated, for the sake of presenting the question, I have made it simple.
In the CustomExecutor.py which is invoked from test-executor.py, if I set it as,
from CustomLogger import Logger as logging

it doesn't work, as it expects the logger to be initialized.
How can the CustomLogger be made to work out of the box similar to default logging, which has to be instantiated only once?

Why not just pass the logger you created in test.py to the functions you want to call, like this
Function in CustomExecutor.py
def iterative_executor(logging, iter_cnt=2):
    for i in range(iter_cnt):
        logging.info(f"Current iteration cnt {i}")

test-executor.py

def main():
    logging = CustomLogger.Logger('sample-run', {
        'cnt' : 10
    })
    logging.info("Starting run")
    iterative_executor(logging, 1)
    logging.info("Done with execution")



Or second approach, Create the logger object in the CustomLogger.py class and import that in another class, like this
test-executor.py
import CustomLogger
from CustomExecutor import iterative_executor


def main():
    logging = CustomLogger.Logger('sample-run', {
        'cnt' : 10
    })
    CustomLogger.logging = logging
    logging.info("Starting run")
    iterative_executor(1)
    logging.info("Done with execution")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

CustomLogger.py
import json
import logging
import os

class StreamLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, k_dict={}, level=logging.DEBUG):
        super().__init__(name, level)

        streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] [%(funcName)s] %(message)s')
        streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.addHandler(streamHandler)

class Logger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, k_dict, level=logging.DEBUG):
        super().__init__(name, level)
        self.k_dict = k_dict
        self.json_logging = False
        if 'TRANSFORM_TO_JSON' in os.environ:
            self.json_logging = True
        self.stream_logger = StreamLogger(name, k_dict)

    def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.json_logging:
            self.stream_logger.info(self._transform_to_json(msg), *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.stream_logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def json_transform(self, msg):
        msg_dict = self.k_dict
        msg_dict['message'] = msg

        return json.dumps(msg_dict)

custom_logging = Logger('sample-run', {'cnt': 10})

CustomExecutor.py
from CustomLogger import custom_logging as logging


def iterative_executor(iter_cnt=2):
    for i in range(iter_cnt):
        logging.info(f"Current iteration cnt {i}")



I could do that, it would be a method signature leak to pass logging to each and every method and wanted to avoid that.

@madmatrix Okay I will gave you another apporach
